# Hyperparameter tune for Tensorflow with hyper-engine

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, hyperparameters

I find hyper-engine python tool on
https://github.com/maxim5/hyper-engine.

The example in only using mnist.
https://github.com/maxim5/hyper-engine/tree/master/hyperengine/examples.

How can I feed my own data like this example below:
https://github.com/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples/blob/master/notebooks/5_DataManagement/build_an_image_dataset.ipynb

Comment: Please clarify your question. Is this a tensorflow question - how to feed data into `sess.run()`? Is it a dataset question - how to read files from disk?

Answer (score 0):

HyperEngine supports custom data provider, the closest example is [this one](https://github.com/maxim5/hyper-engine/blob/master/hyperengine/examples/4_1_word2vec_embedding.py): it's generating word pairs from the text, not images, but the API is more or less clear. Basically, you only need to implement `next_batch` method:

```
def next_batch(self, batch_size):
  pass
```

So if you want to train your network on a set of images on a disk, you simply need to write an iterator over files and yield numpy arrays upon calling the next batch.

**But there is a but**. Currently, HyperEngine is accepting only *numpy arrays* from `next_batch`. The [example](https://github.com/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples/blob/master/notebooks/5_DataManagement/build_an_image_dataset.ipynb) you refer to is working with TF queue API and `read_images` function is producing *tensors*, so you can't simply copy the code. Hopefully, will be a better support for various tensorflow APIs, including estimators, dataset API, queues, etc.